# How to import existing database on Azure?

Tags: azure, ubuntu-14.04

I have completed with the process of creating webapp + mysql with different deployment slots. I have also configure bitbucket on Azure new portal (https://portal.azure.com). I have Linux system.

I want to import existing Database, from local to Azure. I have tried with Mysql workbench but its giving me Failed connection.

So my question is, How to import existing Database on Azure portal?

Comment: I'm able to connect to the ClearDB offer by using MySQL Workbench, so it should work in general. How did you setup your connection?

Comment: I am not very much comfortable with Azure configuration. As i am doing Rnd. My webapp generated data connection string like "Data Source=tcp:testdb.database.windows.net,1111;Initial Catalog=testdb;User ID=testdb@testdb;Password=@abc123
"
I simply install mysql workbench on my machin. and click on new connection.
Following details i am putting  in fields:
Hostname:  tcp:testdb.database.windows.net,1111
Port: 3306
Username: testdb@testdb
Password: @abc123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your comment from yesterday, you either try to connect to an Azure SQL Database with the MySQL Workbench, which will not work.
Use another tool like [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx) or [JetBrains DataGrip](http://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) for that.

Or you're using the ClearDB MySQL offer.
Then your connection string should look like this "Server=eu-cdbr-azure-north-b.cloudapp.net;Port=3306;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;", which I was assuming when you wrote that you used the webapp+mysql template.

Or you're hosting your own MySQL Server as a Virtual Maschine, which would also be a different server name, e.g. yourpublicipdnsname.northeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

Comment: Thanks! I have connected with ClearDB using Mysql workbench.